# Parsing Single Column List(Of String)() to two column List based on values

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following List(Of String)()

```
buttons=10
button_exit=10
button_x=600
button_y=400
;
button_text_01=Start
button_program_01=Start.exe
button_bckcolor_01=&H0080FFFF
;
button_text_02=Second
button_program_02=Second.exe
button_bckcolor_02=&H00FFFF80
;
button_text_03=Load
button_program_03=Load.exe
button_bckcolor_03=&H0080C0FF
```

and I would like to add some of it's values on a new List such as:

```
Column1  Column2
------   -----
Start    Start.exe
Second   Second.exe
Load     Load.exe
```

So, the only values that I need are `button_text_xx` and `button_program_xx`. Any ideas?

Below is my buggy code attempt.

```
If listSCMenuSection.Count > 0 Then
    For Each item In listSCMenuSection
        ' MsgBox(listSCMenuSection.IndexOf(item).ToString)
        If item.Contains("button_caption_") Then
            dtButtons.Rows.Add(item.ToString, 0)
        End If
    Next

'Loop through

For Each item In listSCMenuSection
    If item.Contains("button_program_") Then
        Dim index As Integer = -1
        Dim sIndex As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To dtButtons.Rows.Count
            If i.ToString.Count < 10 Then
                sIndex = "0" & i.ToString
            Else
                sIndex = i.ToString
            End If
            Dim rows As DataRow() = dtButtons.[Select]("Name Like '%" & sIndex & "%'")
            If rows.Count = 1 Then
                index = dtButtons.Rows.IndexOf(rows(0))
                'Add the button_program to the corresponding index of button_caption

                dtButtons.Rows(index)(1) = item.ToString

            ElseIf rows.Count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("You have more than one buttons declared in the ini file for: " & item.ToString)
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next
        'If listSCMenuSection.IndexOf(item).ToString.Count < 10 Then
        '    sIndex = "0" & listSCMenuSection.IndexOf(item).ToString
        'Else
        '    sIndex = listSCMenuSection.IndexOf(item).ToString
        'End If
    End If
    Next
    Dim x As Integer = 0
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please configure the 'MENU' section in the Ini file", "Section keys missing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If
```

Comment: You mean entries are separated by a line containing `;`, and that you want to select from each entry the value of the key starting with `button_text_` and `button_program_`? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes. Sometimes, however, the ; might not be present.

Comment: So your question is _"Please write a parser for this format for me"_? It closely resembles the ini file format, have you tried anything?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes. I have tried but it's buggy. I will paste my code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to parse the data in the string list. It seems to be loaded from a text file, in a format that resembles an ini file. The line `"buttons=X"` defines there are X buttons.

One approach is as follows:

- Read the number of buttons
- Loop from 1 to the number of buttons
- For each `button_n`
- Try to find each of the three values (text, program, background) and add the buttons to a list

This can be implemented as such:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ButtonEntry
{
    public int Number { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Load data...
        var data = new List<string>
        {
            "buttons=2",
            ";",
            "button_text_01=a",
            "button_text_02=b",
            "button_program_02=p",
            "button_bckcolor_02=c",
        };

        // Find number of buttons.
        string buttonString = ReadData(data, "buttons");
        int buttonCount = int.Parse(buttonString);

        var buttons = new List<ButtonEntry>();

        // Fill each button.
        for (int b = 1; b <= buttonCount; b++)
        {
            var button = new ButtonEntry
            {
                Number = b
            };

            string needle = "button_text_" + b.ToString("D2");  
            button.Text = ReadData(data, needle);
            needle = "button_program_" + b.ToString("D2");  
            button.Program = ReadData(data, needle);
            needle = "button_bckcolor_" + b.ToString("D2"); 
            button.BackgroundColor = ReadData(data, needle);

            buttons.Add(button);
        }

        foreach (var button in buttons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Button {0}: {1}, {2}, {3}", button.Number, button.Text, button.Program, button.BackgroundColor);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the line in <paramref name="data" /> that starts with
    /// <paramref name="needle" /> followed by "=", returning the 
    /// value after "=" or null when not found.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ReadData(List<string> data, string needle)
    {
        var line = data.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(needle));
        if (line == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return line.Substring(line.IndexOf("=") + 1);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Button 1: a, , 
Button 2: b, p, c
```

This doesn't do any error handling and it doesn't perform that well, as it loops the entire list every time to find the given entry, but given the list stays small it can be considered "good enough". And if you didn't want C#, you shouldn't have tagged the question as such.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am trying your code now but I have some trouble converting  var button = new ButtonEntry {                Number = b }; to VB.NET. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution(my bug). Your answer is awesome!